# Using Android & Google App Engine on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm developing an app with backend and I decided to try using Google App Engine for my backend. Since I'm really new on Google App Engine, I'm little bit confused with the logic.

Basically, I have a couple of model classes to represent my object types. Lets say one of them is User and another is Item. Users have items and an item can belong more than one user. So User X can have 25 items including Item A, and User Y can have totally different 20 items and also the Item A.

Right now my User class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String photoURL;

    //All getters and setters...
}
```

And my Item class is approximately same. One of my questions is, where should I add some kind of list, like a list of Items into User. And which annotation should I use? What will that annotation provide me as a result (a reference, an id or a complete object)?

Another question related to this is, in my endpoint class, how can I get a list of Items that a specific User has (or list of Users that owns a specific Item)?

One last totally unrelated question, should I do anything to make `id` auto increment or will it be automatic if I won't provide any id while inserting an item?

Comment: It all depends on your usecase and how you want it. You can embedded objects or put references to other objects: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#embedded-classes and regarding ids a few paragraphs higher: *"The @Id field can be of type `Long`, `long`, or `String`. If you use `Long` and save an entity with a `null` id, a numeric value will be generated for you using the standard GAE allocator for this kind. If you use `String` or the primitive `long` type, values will never be autogenerated."* Ids are probably not incremental, I guess randomly distributed.

Comment: Thanks @zapl, I got my answer about @Id. About the embedded classes, I don't think it's my solution. I want to be able to reach items from both classes independently. I saw structures like `Ref<User> ` or annotations like `@Load` or `@Parent` but I'm not sure if any of these is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, [these](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#relationships) *are* the droids you're looking for. Key or Ref to build relations, Auto `@Load`ed in case you would load them anyways so objectify can [batch](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BestPractices#use-batch-gets-instead-of-queries) requests. Parent probably not, the use for that is limited. PS: would recommend to read that documentation once or twice, it's a little unorganised but full of useful information in places you wouldn't expect :)

Comment: I quickly checked the entire article (will read carefully). So, in this case I can add `List<Key<Item>> items = new ArrayList<Key<Item>>();` line to my User class. But how will I search for the Users who has the same Item? Can you maybe write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can search in the datastore for 2 things: keys and indexed properties.

```
class Thing {
   @Id Long id;
   @Index String property;
}
```

At some point you save some entities

```
Thing thing1 = new Thing();
thing1.property = "yes";
Thing thing2 = new Thing();
thing2.property = "no";
ofy().save().entities(thing1, thing2).now();
```

Now you can search for all entities based on their indexed properties. E.g. for all things with `property == "yes"`.

```
List<Thing> things = ofy().load().type(Thing.class).filter("property", "yes").list();
```

Would return exactly `thing1`.

The same works with Lists of properties. And it works with lists of references/keys to other properties.

```
class User {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index List<Key<Item>> items;
}

class Item {
    @Id
    Long id;
}

List<User> searchUsersWithItem(long itemId) {
    Key<Item> itemKey = Key.create(Item.class, itemId);
    return ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("items", itemKey).list();
}
List<User> searchUsersWithItem(Item item) {
    return ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("items", item).list();
}
// just loads all the referenced items in the owner
List<Item> searchItemsWithOwner(User owner) {
    return new ArrayList<Item>(ofy().load().<Item>values(owner.items).values());
}
```

`filter` works with refs, keys and entitiy instances.

To be found things must be indexed https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes / https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries

What's left for you to decide is how you model your relation. There are multiple ways. A user that owns a set of items which can be owned by set of users is actually a many-to-many relation. You could represent it like

```
class User { List<Key<Item>> items; }
class Item { }
```

or

```
class User { }
class Item { List<Key<User>> owners; }
```

or

```
class User { List<Key<Item>> items; }
class Item { List<Key<User>> owners; }
```

or even

```
class User { }
class Item { }
class Ownership { Key<Item> item; Key<User> user; }
```

Each approach has it's ups and downs with respect to data consistency and searchability / performance. In the initial example it's trivial to search for all items of a user since all you have to to is to load that one user and you have the list of items. The other direction requires the query approach.

So with respect to search performance you benefit from having the list of owners in the items as well as the list of items in the user because that way you don't need queries at all. The big downside becomes data consistency. If you fail to update both user and item at the same time you can have items that believe to be owned by a user where the user thinks different.

The last approach, using an explicit "Ownership" entity is essentially the traditional pivot / junction table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29 that is the result of transforming a many-many relation into 2 one-many relations. Using that would result in easy consistency, but the worst query performance.

Parent relations can sometimes be useful but only if there is an actual 1 to many relation where the parent needs to exist.

Also note how keys are not foreign keys like in traditional SQL databases as they can exist without an entity. So you'll have to take care of consistency regardless of what you do.

Comment: Thank you so much for the impressive answer! I feel bad about still having questions. When I try to return List<Item>, I get such error: `Parameterized type com.googlecode.objectify.Ref<> not supported.` I was able to avoid this error by adding `@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)` annotation to the method but in that case I can't use the getter method in Android code.