# How to return a list of custom objects on Objectify

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm working on an Android project which uses Google App Engine for backend as described here: [Using Android & Google App Engine on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701147/using-android-google-app-engine-on-android-studio).

I have some model classes on the backend side like User and Item, and I'm trying to return a list of Items user has.

```
public List<Ref<Item>> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

When I try to `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
>   There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Parameterized type com.googlecode.objectify.Ref≤backend.model.Item> not supported.

I checked some other questions here and was able to build the project without errors by adding `@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)` annotation to my getter method. But after adding this line, I cannot see this method on Android app side.

Any idea how to make it possible to get a list of Items on Android side?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by saving/retrieving object that contains serialized collection. Class Lesson implements Serializable.

Language.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Serialize;

@Entity
public class Language {

    @Id
    private String key;
    private String title;
    @Serialize
    private List<Lesson> lessons;  //here collection

    //getters/setters ommited
}
```

LanguageService.java

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.minspok.entity.Language;

@Api(name = "langapi", version = "v1", description = "langapi")

public class LanguageService {

    static{
        ObjectifyService.register( Language.class );
    }


    @ApiMethod(name = "get")
    public Language getLanguage(@Named("key") String key){
        Language language = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Language.class,  
                        key)).now();
        return language;
    }


    @ApiMethod(name = "create")
    public void createLanguage(Language language){
        ofy().save().entity(language);   
    }
}
```

Helpful reading: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a small question, I thought it should be `List<Ref<Lesson>> lessons` instead of `List<Lesson> lessons`, am I wrong? I'm not sure about the difference /:

Comment: I completely unaware what class Ref in your code is. Have no idea about it. What is it? The code in my answer is part of my project and it is absolutely working code.

Comment: Using `@Serialize` will store the data with java serialization - usually unwise. You could just drop the `@Serialize` and objectify will break down the data and store it as native `EmbeddedEntity` structures, which is far preferable. But both of those approaches embed the objects in the parent, which presumably is not what the OP wants. Personally I would eliminate Ref from the API, only pass real objects back and forth across your API boundaries. You don't want Refs in your android client.