# Why does this Objectify code returns a list of 1 object instead of 3?

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

I am trying to setup a Unit Test framework for a GAE application that uses Objectify to access Datastore. This test was written, and when executed in a local environment it failed.

The following is the code:

```
public class ObjectifyTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                    new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig());
     private Closeable ofySession;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         helper.setUp();
         ofySession = ObjectifyService.begin();          
     }

     @After
     public void tearDown() {
         ofySession.close();
         helper.tearDown();
     }

     @Test
     public void testApiHandlerGetTrackerTag() {
         Date now = new Date();

         TrackerTag tag1= new TrackerTag();
         tag1.setHash("...");

         TrackerTag tag2= new TrackerTag();
         tag2.setHash("...");

         TrackerTag tag3= new TrackerTag();
         tag3.setHash("...");

         OfyService.ofy().save().entities(tag1, tag2, tag3).now();

         assertEquals(3,OfyService.ofy().load().type(TrackerTag .class).list().size());
     }

}
```

This test fails at assertEquals(...) because the call to Objectify returns a list of size 1, instead of the expected 3. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738151/how-to-return-a-list-of-custom-objects-on-objectify) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Still no clue as to why it behaves so. Any Objectify experts here too help?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the class TrackerTag?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `LocalServiceTestHelper` is to simulate eventual consistency. This is generally not what you want when writing tests. You can force test behavior to strong consistency by calling `setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy()` on the `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig` object you pass in to the helper.

Comment: Will give this a try and get back to you here if it works. Thanks!